# What does psconfigui.exe do?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sharepoint-foundation

just wanted to know what this application does.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/sowmyaa/archive/2012/03/20/sharepoint-2010-psconfig-basic-guidelines.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PSConfigUI.exe is UI based "SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard", 
you can either run it from the 12/14/15 hive's bin folder

or

you can run it from the Start >All program > Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Products > "SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard"

[image]

SharePoint also has a command line version of this comman which psConfig.exe. Check this [technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

Answer (score 6):

It is the "SharePoint Products and Technologies Configuration Wizard". Used for configuring SharePoint after installation, updates, farm modifications etc.